# Flex item alignment issue in Firefox

Tags: firefox, flexbox, width, horizontal-scrolling, absolute

**The desired effect:**

I have a scrolling row of tiles, with the first tile aligned to the left of its container (.row).

When the user hovers over an individual tile it scales up 1.5x in ALL directions.

*(See pen linked below.)*

**Issue:**

The scaling effect works in all browsers I have tested but, in Firefox  the alignment of the scrolling row is wrong (note the numbers in the tiles) and the browser seems to be adding left positioning.

Commenting out both “justify-content: center” on the .row element and the margin-left setting in javascript achieves proper alignment in Firefox but the scale-up effect changes (i.e. the tile does not expand to the left).

**Please note:**

1. "ScrollLeft" value never equals calculated value of “Scroll Row Width”
2. Value of “Scroll Row Width” is substantially smaller in Firefox than in Chrome, Safari or Opera.
3. Scrolling row never reached “rowEnd” although it clearly reaches the last tile.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<div class="row" @scroll="rowScrollCount(); scrollPosition();">

  <div  class="row__inner" @mouseenter="rowEntered(); scrollingRowWidth(); scrollPosition(); scrollArrows();" @mouseleave="rowLeft()">

    <div v-for="i in 20" :class="`tile tile${i}`" @mouseenter="hoveredEl(); scaleTileUp()" @mouseleave= scaleTileDown()>

      <p :class="`tileNum tileNum${i}`">{{ i }}</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  .row {
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: 75%;
      height: 100%;
      scrollbar-width: none; 
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border: 1px solid violet;
      position: absolute;

  }

  .row__inner {
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/dresscode/pen/JjjwbOY